# Node.js indicating unexpected token beyond end of file

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error

I'm developing a pretty simple bot in Node.js, and it won't launch anymore.  Node.js is indicating an unexpected token error, but the line number listed is past the end of the file.  Specifically, the error is:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Bot\jovial_bot.js:294
});
 ^

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at Module._compile (module.js:427:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

The last line in the program is `} );` However, the last line is line number 293.  Adding newlines to the end of the file increases the line number reported by Node.js.   As far as I can tell, I do not have any unmatch parenthesis.  I tried adding ( to the end of the file, and the error changed to "Unexpected token }".  Adding " ({ " changed the error to "Unexpected end of input".  I don't know where to continue with this.  Thank you in advance for the help.

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kunkelwe/VEBtH/
And I'm using this API: https://github.com/alaingilbert/Turntable-API/blob/master/turntable_data/deregistered.js

Comment: care to show us the rest of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `}` on line `102`. You open a function called `toggle_mode` on line `74` but you never put a closing `}`.

```
...

function toggle_mode( mode ) {
    switch( mode ) {
        ...
    }
// ** missing a '}' here **

//Events////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bot.on( 'ready', function( data ) { //Join the room
    bot.roomRegister(ROOMID);
} );

...
```